# Most efficient method of tagging entries in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm constructing a database of entries that take tags denoting the category or categories to which they belong.

There are approximately 250 tags for thousands of observations. Each observation must take at least one, but generally not more than 10-15 tags.

My intention was to create a second table, join the entries using a unique identifier, and then set the tags as binary variables, using each tag as a column.

I recall reading somewhere that this approach is inefficient for large tables, although I can't seem to find any recommendations for alternative approaches. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Additional info in comment below, pasted here for convenience:

I'm going to call the data using Python's sqlite3 module, where it will be used as a portion of the inputs for an optimization model (time to reach datapoint given a particular vector of demographic information).

I don't anticipate needing to modify the data regularly, but cleaning/massaging and updating may be required in the event of unforeseen changes.

I expect to access each entry at least once for every tag it has, once the dataset is prepped for analysis. I should be able to store the dataframes in RAM for my optimization work, so I don't expect to need to retrieve the data points more than that.

Comment: Efficiency is not absolute. It depends on what you plan to do with your data. How are you going to access it? How often? Will you modify it after your initial insert and so on.

Comment: I'm going to call the data using Python's sqlite3 module, where it will be used as a portion of the inputs for an optimization model (time to reach datapoint given a particular vector of demographic information).

I don't anticipate needing to modify the data regularly, but cleaning/massaging and updating may be required in the event of unforeseen changes.

I expect to access each entry at least once for every tag it has, once the dataset is prepped for analysis. I might run this multiple times to get a map of e.g. travel time to nearest datapoint for a city.